# Angular2 cannot find module '../webservices'

Tags: web-services, angular, angular2-services

In my app.component.ts I import my webservices module as such:
[image]

But I'm getting red squiggly lines, even though I think I should be importing it correctly. Here's my app structure:
[image]

Here's my web service module:
[image]

Comment: it should be `import { WebService } from './webservices/webservices'`

Comment: if you use a "good" IDE, it will suggest the right imports for you automatically.

Comment: @Blauhirn Visual Studio Code has path prediction, If you say it's a bad IDE, you probably never tested it and I recommend you to do so. The issue Amanda_Panda is facing is a common error, to import the folder instead of the file simply because you do not specify the .ts of the files when you import them.

Comment: VS Code really is a nice IDE/text editor. And I don't use Windows.

Comment: @Ploppy Surely the greatness of an IDE is not determined by its ability to import paths correctly. I didn't know VSC had this bug, but that is good to know and kind of disappointing.

Comment: @Blauhirn What are you even talking about ??? It's not a bug...

Comment: don't / can't you issue a "import automatically" or anything similar in VSC when you click on an unknown reference? That is what I meant initially. Thus, one wouldn't have to write down the imports manually in the first place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Must be:

```
import {Webservice} from './webservices/webservices.services';
```

Comment: Making that change still give me the error Cannot find module './webservices/webservices'.